# Deploy co django en heroku falla por que no se puede hacer collectstatic con whiteNoise

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, deployment

Hola gracias por su ayuda de antemano

trato de hace un deploy en heroku pero recibo el siguiete error y no tengo idea de que es lo que pasa les agradeceria mucho su ayuda:

```
remote:          webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot
remote:        Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote:        relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Primer *deploy*...disculpen mi ignorancia pero no tengo idea de que es ese archivo `webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot`,por lo que entiendo hace referencia a un archivo que no existe pero como rastreo ese `webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot`?

Comment: en tu pagina pones iconos?

Comment: La fuente que usa tu proyecto no esta instalada en el servidor donde se hace el despliegue. Es decir, que tienes que instalarlo. Otra es que puedes desactivar el CollectStatic para que logre funcionar (?.

Comment: Los iconos son de Font Awesome, y la fuente la voy a cambiar a sans-serif,uso boostrap también pero si esta descargado e integrado en los archivos estaticos